# Subtract from previous rows' average with a condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have been working on an inventory problem. I have a table, which I will be providing a sample of, that has stock code, date, amount(in dollars), quantity of the stock and type. I have 2 different types 0 and 1. 0 means that the row represents a stock 'entry' movement. I needed to check the order of the movements, and if there are more than one entry movements back to back, then I had to take the average of those rows' unit price, for the same stock codes. My code gave me the results I wanted;

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #cte
SELECT  *
INTO    #cte
FROM    (
    VALUES  ('A',N'2024-02-10',100,5 , 0)
    ,   ('A',N'2024-02-12',100,2 , 1)
    ,   ('B',N'2024-02-13', 500, 6, 0)
    ,   ('B',N'2024-02-21', 250, 4, 0)
    ,   ('A',N'2024-03-01', 400, 16 , 0)
    ,   ('A',N'2024-03-10', 300, 10, 0)
    ,   ('B',N'2024-03-19', 450, 45, 1)
    ,   ('A',N'2024-04-30', 500, 10,0 )
    ,   ('A',N'2024-04-30', 650, 5 , 0)
    ,   ('A',N'2024-04-30', 800, 20, 1)
    ,   ('B',N'2024-05-20', 760,76, 1)

) cte (stock_code, stock_date,stock_amount,stock_quantity,stock_type)


;with inventory as
(select

stock_code,
stock_date,
stock_amount,
stock_quantity,
stock_amount/nullif(stock_quantity,0) as unit_price,
case when stock_type = 0 then 'entry' else 'exit' end as st_type,
    CASE WHEN stock_type = 0 THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY stock_code, stock_type ORDER BY stock_date) END AS entry_group,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY stock_date) AS order_id,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY stock_date) - ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY stock_code,stock_type ORDER BY stock_date)  as diff

from
#cte
)


SELECT  *,
    CASE WHEN  st_type = 'entry' THEN 
        CASE 
        WHEN Lag(st_type) OVER (ORDER BY stock_date) = 'entry' or Lead(st_type) OVER (ORDER BY stock_date) = 'entry' or (Lag(st_type) OVER (ORDER BY stock_date) = 'entry' and Lead(st_type) OVER (ORDER BY stock_date) = 'entry')
            THEN avg(unit_price) OVER (PARTITION BY st_type, diff)
            ELSE unit_price  END 
        ELSE unit_price END AS avg_unit_price
FROM inventory
ORDER BY stock_date;
```

The output of this query is:

| stock_code | stock_date | stock_amount | stock_quantity | unit_price | st_type | entry_group | order_id | diff | avg_unit_price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2024-02-10 | 100 | 5 | 20 | entry | 1 | 1 | 0 | 20 |
| A | 2024-02-12 | 100 | 2 | 50 | exit | NULL | 2 | 1 | 50 |
| B | 2024-02-13 | 500 | 6 | 83 | entry | 1 | 3 | 2 | 72 |
| B | 2024-02-21 | 250 | 4 | 62 | entry | 2 | 4 | 2 | 72 |
| A | 2024-03-01 | 400 | 16 | 25 | entry | 2 | 5 | 3 | 27 |
| A | 2024-03-10 | 300 | 10 | 30 | entry | 3 | 6 | 3 | 27 |
| B | 2024-03-19 | 450 | 45 | 10 | exit | NULL | 7 | 6 | 10 |
| A | 2024-04-30 | 800 | 20 | 40 | exit | NULL | 10 | 8 | 40 |
| A | 2024-04-30 | 500 | 10 | 50 | entry | 4 | 8 | 4 | 90 |
| A | 2024-04-30 | 650 | 5 | 130 | entry | 5 | 9 | 4 | 90 |
| B | 2024-05-20 | 760 | 76 | 10 | exit | NULL | 11 | 9 | 10 |

As seen, when there are back to back 'entry' movements, the avg_unit_price equals to the average of them. Else, the avg_unit_price stays the same as unit_price.

What I want to achieve is that to have a query (which can be implemented as a view) that gaves me the following result:

| stock_code | stock_date | stock_amount | stock_quantity | unit_price | st_type | entry_group | order_id | diff | avg_unit_price | diff_from_prev_entries |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2024-02-10 | 100 | 5 | 20 | entry | 1 | 1 | 0 | 20 | NULL |
| A | 2024-02-12 | 100 | 2 | 50 | exit | NULL | 2 | 1 | 50 | 30 |
| B | 2024-02-13 | 500 | 6 | 83 | entry | 1 | 3 | 2 | 72 | NULL |
| B | 2024-02-21 | 250 | 4 | 62 | entry | 2 | 4 | 2 | 72 | NULL |
| A | 2024-03-01 | 400 | 16 | 25 | entry | 2 | 5 | 3 | 27 | NULL |
| A | 2024-03-10 | 300 | 10 | 30 | entry | 3 | 6 | 3 | 27 | NULL |
| B | 2024-03-19 | 450 | 45 | 10 | exit | NULL | 7 | 6 | 10 | 62 |
| A | 2024-04-30 | 800 | 20 | 40 | exit | NULL | 10 | 8 | 40 | 13 |

Let me explain; I want to see the difference for each 'exit' record from the latest previous 'entry' record for each stock code. For example, for stock_code A, all the entry records are null. The first exit record of A has an avg_unit_price of 50. Checking the previous records, it is seen that the first row is an entry record of A that has an avg_unit_price of 20. By checking the difference(subtracting the avg_unit_values) the new column diff_from_prev_entries gives us a value of 30. There is one mor exit record of A, which is at the end of the table that has a avg_unit_price of 40. Checking the "latest" previous entry of A, which has an avg_unit_price of 27, it subtracts the values and gaves an answer of 13. This scenario goes the same for the stock code B.

If there is a way, I can have the diffence between only the entry record of the same stocks instead of a NULL value in the new column. If an entry record has other entry records before it, it can show the difference between them. For example for the second entry movements of A has an avg_unit_ptice of 27, while the first one is 20. Hence the difference is -7.

I have tried self joining the tables but the results didn't make sense at all. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Is your average unit price really correct? you don't partition by stock code for example, plus i see some other issues.

Comment: Thank you for your reminder! The table I provided is actually an example of my original table. Unit prices are more accurate in there, in this question, I just wanted to provide a table that has the same characteristics as mine. I have ten thousand different stock codes in my original table and more than 200.000 rows. @siggemannen

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I completely understood your request in the second to last paragraph (difference from last ENTRY), but I think this either answers it or provides enough primitives for you to easily get it. It does group the inputs and calculates an average price and finds the unit price difference between exits and the oldest past input for a given part.

Because I wasn't certain what you wanted in that paragraph I kept the CTEs simple and used lots of them, that should also make it easier to follow what's going on (and I added many comments for the same reason). You could combine some of them, but the query optimizer should make it nearly as efficient so you probably don't need to bother.

Also, this is completely view friendly, with no temporary tables or variables needed.

```
with cteIn as (--The input sample data, your real table replaces cteIn 
    SELECT * 
    FROM    (VALUES  ('A',CONVERT(DATE,'2024-02-10'),100,5 , 0)
        , ('A',N'2024-02-12',100,2 , 1)
        , ('B',N'2024-02-13', 500, 6, 0)
        , ('B',N'2024-02-21', 250, 4, 0)
        , ('A',N'2024-03-01', 400, 16 , 0)
        , ('A',N'2024-03-10', 300, 10, 0)
        , ('B',N'2024-03-19', 450, 45, 1)
        , ('A',N'2024-04-30', 500, 10,0 )
        , ('A',N'2024-04-30', 650, 5 , 0)
        , ('A',N'2024-04-30', 800, 20, 1)
        , ('B',N'2024-05-20', 760,76, 1)
    ) cte (stock_code, stock_date,stock_amount,stock_quantity,stock_type)
    --NOTE: stock_type=0 means Entry and runs must be grouped, 
    -- but 1 is exit and they stand alone
), ctePrep1 as ( --prepare to generate groups, runs of ENTRY get grouped
    SELECT * --so we need to know what the last transaction was, assume EXIT for first
        , LAG(I.stock_type, 1, 1) --Find the most recent entry FOR THIS PRODUCT
            over (PARTITION BY stock_code ORDER BY stock_date) as LastTran
    FROM cteIn as I --REPLACE cteIn with the your real table name
), ctePrep2 as ( --Compare the current entry with the most recent, use it to tell if group# goes up
    SELECT *, CASE WHEN stock_type = 0 AND stock_type = LastTran 
        THEN 0 ELSE 1 END as GroupContrib --NOTE, ENTRIES get grouped, EXITS do not
    FROM ctePrep1 as G --But ENTRIES for a new group if immediately following an EXIT (or if first)
), ctePrep3 as ( --Calculate the group#, it's the sum of the transitions that
    SELECT *     --have occured BEFORE this transaction
        , SUM(GroupContrib) OVER (PARTITION BY stock_code ORDER BY stock_date 
            ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) as GroupID
    FROM ctePrep2 as G 
), cteGrouped as ( --Now group entries and calculate the average unit price for the group
    SELECT stock_code, MAX(stock_date) as stock_date, SUM(stock_amount) as stock_amount
        , SUM(stock_quantity) as stock_quantity, stock_type, GroupID
        , SUM(stock_amount) / SUM(stock_quantity) as unit_price
    FROM ctePrep3 as G 
    GROUP BY stock_code, GroupID, stock_type
), cteTieBack as (--For each group, find the entry with the largest group number 
    SELECT *  --that occured before this transaction, leave NULL if none
        , (SELECT MAX(GroupID) as LastEntry FROM cteGrouped as L 
            WHERE L.GroupID < G.GroupID AND L.stock_code = G.stock_code 
                AND L.stock_type = 0) as LastEntryGroup
    FROM cteGrouped as G
), cteTied as (--Do the JOIN to pull date and price info from most recent entry
    SELECT G.*, L.unit_price as LastEntryUnitPrice, L.stock_date as LastEntryDate
    FROM cteTieBack as G LEFT OUTER JOIN cteTieBack as L 
        on G.stock_code = L.stock_code AND G.LastEntryGroup = L.GroupID 
) --Now just format the output, more columns are avaiable
SELECT G.stock_code , G.stock_date , G.stock_amount, G.stock_quantity
    , CASE WHEN G.stock_type = 0 THEN 'entry' ELSE 'exit' END as stock_type
    , G.unit_price, G.LastEntryUnitPrice as prev_unit_price
    , G.unit_price - G.LastEntryUnitPrice as unit_price_diff
    , G.GroupID as this_tran_group, G.LastEntryGroup as last_entry_group
    , G.lastentrydate 
FROM cteTied as G
ORDER BY G.stock_code , G.GroupID
```

This gives the output

| stock_code | stock_date | stock_amount | stock_quantity | stock_type | unit_price | prev_unit_price | unit_price_diff | this_tran_group | last_entry_group | lastentrydate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2024-02-10 | 100 | 5 | entry | 20 | NULL | NULL | 1 | NULL | NULL |
| A | 2024-02-12 | 100 | 2 | exit | 50 | 20 | 30 | 2 | 1 | 2024-02-10 |
| A | 2024-04-30 | 1200 | 36 | entry | 33 | 20 | 13 | 3 | 1 | 2024-02-10 |
| A | 2024-04-30 | 800 | 20 | exit | 40 | 33 | 7 | 4 | 3 | 2024-04-30 |
| A | 2024-04-30 | 650 | 5 | entry | 130 | 33 | 97 | 5 | 3 | 2024-04-30 |
| B | 2024-02-21 | 750 | 10 | entry | 75 | NULL | NULL | 1 | NULL | NULL |
| B | 2024-03-19 | 450 | 45 | exit | 10 | 75 | -65 | 2 | 1 | 2024-02-21 |
| B | 2024-05-20 | 760 | 76 | exit | 10 | 75 | -65 | 3 | 1 | 2024-02-21 |